# Any sharpziplib commercial support?

Tags: sharpziplib

Govt client doesn't like open source. Legacy app used sharpziplib without getting permission. They'll pay for support, so we don't have to rewrite (your tax dollars at work), but I can't find anyone who provides paid support for sharpziplib.

Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: Army IA guy said if my company promised support, they'd allow it. Replacing with commercial was an option, but would have slipped the project due date, and that's pretty much non-negotiable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a GPL project that is fully open source, so paid support is not going to be easily available.

Why can't you buy a commercial zip component and pay for it and support? There are plenty of those around.